# Problem with NOT operator in Swift clauses

Tags: swift, xcode, operators

I'm programming in Swift 5.0 an app to move my character around a world and I've some problems with the NOT (!) operator in the `if` condition body.
I wrote:

```
 if character.!isBlocked {
    character.moveForward()
 }
```

but the compiler say: **Error: ".!" it's not a binary operator**

Instead, if I wrote

```
if character.isBlocked {
        character.turnBack()
     }
```

it works perfectly. Its possible to use a negative clause as `if` condition clause?

Comment: `!` should be applied to `Bool` value, not to the property name. `!character.isBlocked` would work.

Comment: @user28434 Thanks it worked! Please could you explain me what you mean as `Bool` value? Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: A Bool (Boolean) value is represented by either true or false. 'character.isBlocked' returns a boolean value meaning you need to apply 'not' to that whole statement. !(true) = false -> !(character.isBlocked) = character is not blocked

Comment: @marc Thanks a lot for your clear explanation, now I've understand! Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aiming to validate as "if not", then you should implement it as:

```
if !character.isBlocked {
    character.moveForward()
}
```

The logical NOT `!` operator is a ***unary*** ***prefix*** operator:

- Unary: it is for a single target.
- Prefix: it should be before the target.

So, why it should be before `character.isBlocked` but not `isBlocked`?

Because `character.isBlocked` is the boolean to evaluate, `isBlocked` is the property name. The correct syntax is to use `!` to evaluate the whole thing (Boolean value).

Comment: Gotcha, thank you too for your very clear explanation! Solved!